# MongoDB select distinct and where

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

So I'm doing a select distinct which works, but I also want to add another key.

```
$data = $this->db->command(array("distinct" => "scores","key"=>"target_user"));
```

I need something like this: `SELECT DISTINCT target_user FROM scores where seen = 1`

Can it be done in mongo?

Comment: Wait you wanna add a key or add a condition?

Comment: Then you should have looked at the doc page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/ its right there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it as follows by using distinct query :

```
db.scores.distinct("target_user", {"seen":1})
```

Running distinct query using Aggregate Framework is shown below.

Inserted following records into MongoDB.

```
db.scores.insert({target_user:"a",seen:1, name:"name1"})
db.scores.insert({target_user:"a",seen:0, name:"name1"})
db.scores.insert({target_user:"b",seen:1, name:"name2"})
db.scores.insert({target_user:"c",seen:1, name:"name3"})
db.scores.insert({target_user:"d",seen:0, name:"name4"})
```

Then by running the following aggregate query you can find the distinct target_user's where seen = 1. Note that it will also return name field.

```
db.scores.aggregate(
{$match:{seen:1}},
{$group: {_id : "$target_user", name: {$first:"$name"}}},
{$group : {_id : "$_id", name: {$first:"$name"}}}
);
```

Then result will be as follows :

```
"result" : [
    {"_id" : "a","name" : "name1"},
    {"_id" : "b","name" : "name2"},
    {"_id" : "c","name" : "name3"}
]
```

Comment: it works, but it doesn't return all the keys from the database, only the target_user, can I get the other values as well?

Comment: As Sammaye mentioned, you cannot get all fields with distinct query. You have to run aggregate query.

Comment: Hmmm I don't get it I guess what you mean..is that first I have to query for distinct values and after that to a query in the same collection but do it like this: select * where X IN(distinct values)

Comment: Can you give me a short example of aggreagte

Comment: I have added aggregate query example.

Comment: Oh I see so instead of running command distinct I need to run aggregate

Comment: But the distinct value needs to be only the target user, I will test it, until then I will accept your answer, great! thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can. No sure what db layer you are using, but in the native MongoDB driver it is possible

[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.distinct.php)

```
$mongoCollection->distinct("target_user", ['seen' => 1]);
```